# "rmic" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: java, compilar, javac

He estado tratando de compilar algunos programas mediante javac, y por ese lado todo bien, pero al momento de querer generar los stubs y skeletons, y usar el rmic para ello, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
"rmic" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Cabe destacar que ya al buscar dentro de la carpeta bin de mi jdk, este no viene, traté de descargarlo a árte y posteriormente añadirlo, y tampoco funciono, también, ya he modificado algunos valores en las variables del entorno en los PATHS y esto tampoco ayudo mucho.
¿Qué más podría hacer o cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: que version de java tienes? Yo entiendo que RMI fue descontinuado hace demasiado tiempo... la ultima vez que lo use fue hace como unos 9 anhios

Comment: Actualmente tengo el 19, tenia el (creo) 18.0.3 antes de tener este problema, y lo actualice tratando de solucionarlo:/